# Integrated wxsqlite into cocos2dx

Tags: android, xcode

I am a cocos2dx developer.
I use cocos2dx v3.2.

Recently I'm facing a problem when I want to use wxsqlite into cocos2dx on androidPlatform.

When I compile with the "./build_native.py" in terminal, there is something wrong.

Can you tell me how to integrate wxsqlite in cocos2dx to compile on the Android platform?

Comment: `[...] there is something wrong happened` - can you be a little more specific here?

Comment: jni/../../Classes/BaseDB.h:16:22: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
 #include  "sqlite3.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o] Error 1

Comment: Please consider editing your question and add all necessary information.

Comment: in iOS Xcode how to import sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code  Android.mk

```
 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \  
                       ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \  
                       ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp\  
            ../../Classes/sqlite3.c  

    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes
```